# Export csv file with encoding in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, character-encoding

I have the following controller action used to export a csv file

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(int projectId)
        {
            var risks = new RiskRepository().GetRisksByProjectId(projectId);
            var commaDelimmeted =
                    risks.Select(
                        r => r.RiskDescription + "," + r.RiskTypeId.ToString() + "," + r.Likelihood.ToString() + "," + r.Impact + "," + r.Action + "," + r.ActionBy + ",")
                        .ToList();

            string data = commaDelimmeted.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, line) => current + line + Environment.NewLine);

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            // set the header
            var aliasName = "someFile.csv";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + aliasName);
            Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.Output.Write(data);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return File(Response.OutputStream, "application/csv");
        }
```

The output csv file do not show right to left langauge characters properly, so I've set response content encoding header the problem still exists.

Any thoughts?

Edit : Looking at Darin's solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538537/csv-file-encoding-for-cyrillic-characters) post didn't fix my problem , the output shows System.Byte[] in the csv output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414088/how-to-getbytes-in-c-sharp-with-utf8-encoding-with-bom), it turns out the encoding preamble must be appended to the csv data like this :

```
using (var sw = System.IO.File.Create(csvPath))
            {
                var preamble = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
                sw.Write(preamble, 0, preamble.Length);
                var databytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                sw.Write(databytes, 0, data.Length);
            }
```

and this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Have you tried setting the encoding in a meta tag in the HTML?

 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
   Excel won't see the response headers, so it won't know what the Response.Encoding is. The meta tag allows it to find out.
```

Comment: do you mean that I have to append this to my data string?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need it to be a CSV file I'd recommend converting it to use ClosedML (available on NuGet) to generate a proper XLSX file - you can then use the GetMimeMapping function and return a FileStreamResult.